# Q:Calculating value of $E((E(X|Y))^2)$

Tags: probability, variance

Does anybody know what this calculates out to? Is it equivalent to $E(X^2)$?I’m mostly confused about how the exponent works inside the parenthesis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$E((E(X|Y))^2) -(E(E(X|Y)))^2= Var(E(X|Y)) \implies E((E(X|Y))^2)=  Var(E(X|Y))+ (EX)^2 $